# Is every finite descending sequence in [0,1] in convex hull of certain points?

Tags: inequality, polytopes, convex-hulls

Fix a natural number $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and a real number $s\in[0,n]$.

Consider the set $A_s\subset [0,1]^n$ of those sequences $(x_1 \geq\dots\geq x_n)$ in $[0,1]$ with $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i=s$.

Given positive integers $p,q$ there is at most one point $x_s(p,q)\in A_s$ of form $(1\geq\cdots\geq 1\geq a\geq \cdots\geq a\geq 0\geq \cdots \geq 0)$ with $p$ many ones and $q$ many $a$'s ($a$ has to be equal to $\frac{s-p}{q}$)

Now the question is: For which $s$ is it true that $A_s$ is the convex hull of the points $x_s(p,q)$, where $p,q$ range over all positive integers such that $x_s(p,q)$ is well defined.

Examples:

1. If $n=1$, then $A_s=\{(s)\}$ consists of a single point (if $s\in[0,1]$ and is empty otherwise), this point is $x_s(0,0)$ (if $s=1$, then x_s(0,0)=x_s(1,0) but this does not change anything).
2. If $n=2$, then $A_s=\{(x,s-x)\mid \frac s2\leq x\leq \min(s,1)\}$. On the other hand we have the points $x_s(0,0)=(\frac s2,\frac s2)$ (as long as $s\in[0,2]$) and $x_s(1,0)=(1,s-1)$ (as long as $s\in[1,2]$) and $x_s(0,1)=(s,0)$ (as long as $s\in[0,1]$). So the claim is true for all $s\in[0,2]$

Comment: It's far from being clear to me... I don't understand why, in dimension 1 you need to consider more than 2 points for a convex hull. Could you provide an example ?

Comment: well, in dimension 1 you have exactly one point, namely the sequence $(s)$. In this case the question is trivial

Comment: Do you mean that your issue is not in dimension 1 ? But, if it is in dimension 2, you haven't explained how you define your points...

Comment: I did define the points in every dimension. Since it might not have been very clear, I rewrote the question to make it more precise.

Comment: I was at a year-light of understanding it this way... Besides, your $[0,1]$ (continuous interval) shouldn't be $\{0,1\}$ (2 elements set) ? That makes a substantial difference...

Comment: I do mean $[0,1]$, i.e. the continuous interval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a result of L. Dubins (["On extreme points of convex sets"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X62800079), see [also](https://ac.els-cdn.com/0022247X63900635/1-s2.0-0022247X63900635-main.pdf?_tid=5425bf5a-f894-11e7-bc7a-00000aab0f02&acdnat=1515870341_334c2da6860d8724eb8979726eb49266)) to the effect that if $K$ is a polytope and $L$ is a co-dimension $m$ affine space, then each extreme point of $K\cap L$ is a convex combination of at most $m+1$ extreme points of $K$.  (The actual result is for general convex compact sets, but polytopes is all that's needed here.)

In the case at hand $K$ is the polytope whose vertices are all of the form $x_{k,l}=(1,1,\dots,0,0,\dots)$, with the first $k$ coordinates equal to $1$ and the last $l$ coordinates equal to $0$, where $k,l\ge0$ and $k+l=n$.  The affine space $L$ is determined by the single condition that the sum of the coordinates is $s$; it has codimension $m=1$.  Each extreme point of $A_s=K\cap L$ is thus a convex  combination of $m+1=2$ extreme points of $K$.  It is easy to check that  the OP's sought extreme points  are indeed convex combinations of pairs of $x_{k,l}$.

Comment: That does indeed answer my question. Do you happen to know if this proof also gives an explicit algorithm for constructing the required convex combinations (in the case I'm interested in, which should be particularly simple)?

Comment: Not really.  In your case, given a point in your $A_s$ its easy to exhibit a convex combo of extreme points of my $K$ representing it. I suppose you could then doctor those points, maybe in a one-pass process, but I haven't thought through any details.