# Extreme points of subset of set of probability measures

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convex-optimization

Let $\mathcal{P}$ be a set of Borel probability measures on $[0, 1]$ equipped with the weak$^{*}$-topology as described here: [What is the weak*-topology on a set of probability measures?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2111245/what-is-the-weak-topology-on-a-set-of-probability-measures).
Consider for $\rho\in [0, 1]$, $$\mathcal{P}(\rho)=\left\{\nu\in \mathcal{P}:\int_{0}^{1}{td\nu(t)}=\rho\right\}.$$ I can show that this set is convex and compact for the weak$^{*}$-topology. I was wondering what the extreme points of $\mathcal{P}(m)$ are and found that the extreme points are of the form $$\nu=p\delta_{x}+q\delta_{y}$$ with $p, q\geq 0$, $x, y\in [0, 1], p+q=1, px+qy=\rho$ where $\delta_{x}$ denotes the Dirac measure at $x$. Can someone explain to me why they are of this form?

Comment: Shouldn't $px + py=\rho$?

Comment: You are correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not satisfy you, but this is covered by a result of Dubins, cited in my answer [to a previous MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2603757/is-every-finite-descending-sequence-in-0-1-in-convex-hull-of-certain-points/2603988#2603988).  You have a compact convex set $\mathcal P$ of probability measures, its set of extreme points is the set of point masses.  Your $\mathcal P(\rho)$
is the intersection of  $\mathcal P$ and a codimension-1 affine  space, namely the measures $\nu$ cut out by the single equation $\int_0^1 td\nu(t)=\rho$. (This equation is affine in $\nu$.) The Dubins result then tells us that the extreme points of $\mathcal P(\rho)$ are linear combinations of $1+1=2$ extreme points of $\mathcal P$, that is, of pairs of point masses.

I wrote "might not satisfy you" because this post only tells you that the fact you ask about has been noticed before but does not explain *why* the result is true.  Maybe you can examine your proof and see how it squares with Dubins's?

Comment: Thank your for your answer! Could you elaborate why the condition for $\mathcal{P}$ gives a "linear space of co-dimension 1"?

Comment: I wrote "linear" and should have written "affine", as the defining equation is inhomogeneous.  I've fixed the text; sorry about the mistake.

Comment: No problem. Thank you!

Comment: Can you give an explanation why this affine space has codimension 1?

Comment: Not without knowing what you know already.  Informally, as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codimension says: "The subspaces can be defined by the vanishing of a certain number of linear functionals, which if we take to be linearly independent, their number is the codimension."  In your case, one equation, so codimension 1.

Comment: Thank you very much!