# Construct a family of probability vectors with pre-fixed first two moments

Tags: probability, probability-theory, analysis, probability-distributions

Given each fixed $N \in \mathbb{N}_+$ and prescribed $\mu > 0$ and $\sigma > 0$, I am wondering if it is possible to construct a family $\mathcal{F}$ of probability vectors ${\bf p} = (p_0,p_1,\ldots,p_N)$ such that elements of $\mathcal{F}$ all have the same mean value (equal to $\mu$) and same variance (equal to $\sigma^2$)? Putting this question in other words, given an arbitrary probability vector ${\bf p} = (p_0,p_1,\ldots,p_N)$ and denote $$\mu = \sum_{n = 0}^N n\,p_n = \mu \quad \text{and} \quad \gamma = \sum_{n = 0}^N n^2\,p_n,$$ is it possible to construct a family of probability vectors ${\bf q} = (q_0,q_1,\ldots,q_N)$ such that ${\bf q}$ and ${\bf p}$ have the same first and second moments? I appreciate any help in the construction.

Comment: @geetha290krm Almost.  The set of possible $(\mu,\gamma)$ is the convex hull of the finite set  $\{(n,n^2): 0\le n\le N\}$. The methods used in solving https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2603757/is-every-finite-descending-sequence-in-0-1-in-convex-hull-of-certain-points/2603988#2603988 can be used  on this problem.

Comment: @geetha290krm Can you provide explicit construction?

Comment: @kimchilover Can you elaborate the specific construction ?

Comment: Yes: I'm drafting an answer to your question now.

Answer (score 1):

Outline:
First, we identify the points $(\mu,\gamma)$ in the plane that can
be represented as the first two moments of a probability distribution $\mathbf p$ supported on the integers $0,1,\ldots N$. Then we identify those for which the representation is unique. The others, which have more than one such representation, supply examples of parametric families of the sought-for type.  That is, if $(\mu,\gamma)=\sum_{n=0}^N (n,n^2)p_n = \sum_{n=0}^N (n,n^2)r_n$, where  $\sum p_n = \sum r_n =1$ with $p_n\ge0,r_n\ge0$, then all members of the parametric family $\mathbf q = t\mathbf p +(1-t)\mathbf r$, for $t\in[0,1]$ will have $(\mu,\gamma)$ as their common first two moments.

Let $v_n=(n,n^2)$, for $n=0,\ldots,N$ be $N+1$ points in the plane,
let $V=\{v_0,\ldots,v_N\}$,
and let $C$ be their convex hull. In fact, the set of extreme points of $C$ is $V$.  Then the set of possible first two
moments $(\mu,\gamma)$ is exactly the set $C$.  The set $C$ is a subset of the points in the plane where $\mu^2\le\gamma$, but is not equal to it.
For instance, the point $(1/2,1/3)$ is not in $C$ but does obey $1/4\le1/3$; similarly for the point $(N+1,(N+1)^2)$.

By [Caratheodory's convex hull theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_theorem_(convex_hull)), every point in $C$ is contained in either $V$, or in an open line segment connecting two elements of $V$, or the  interior of a triangle all of whose vertices are in $V$.  Call these $N+1 + \binom{N+1}2 +\binom{N+1}3 $ figures the ''Caratheodory pieces'' of $C$. Some points (those in $V$, for instance) show up only once this way, (that is, are contained in only one Caratheodory piece)  as do  those in the line segment connecting $v_0$ and $v_1$.  But the triangle with vertices $v_0,v_1,v_2$ has non-empty intersection with the triangle with vertices $v_1,v_2,v_3$, and any $(\mu,\gamma)$ in that intersection occurs in more than one Caratheodory piece.  A point in a triangle-type Caratheodory piece is (say) $av_i+bv_j +cv_k$, where the probabilities $a,b,c$ sum to $1$.  This corresponds to the $\mathbf p$ vector for which all components vanish  except $p_i=a, p_j=b, p_k=c$. A point in a segment-type piece is (say) $a v_i+bv_j$ where the probabilities $a$ and $b$ add to $1$, which  corresponds to $p_i = a, p_j=b$ and all other $p_n=0$.

The points in $C$  that are  contained in exactly one Caratheodory piece have unique representations by $\mathbf p$ vectors, but those in more than one piece have multiple  representations. In fact, the set of probability vectors representing such a $(\mu,\gamma)$ is a convex set, whose extreme  points are  probability vectors with at most 3 non-zero components, according to a theorem of [Dubins](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82782543.pdf).  That convex set is the desired family of $\mathbf q$ vectors.

Suppose, for illustration, that $(\mu,\gamma)$ is in the interior  of the the triangle with vertices $v_i,v_j,v_k$. Then  we can solve the equations
$$ v_i a +v_j b+v_kc=(\mu,\gamma)$$ for the non-negative unknowns  $a,b,c$ subject to $a+b+c=1$ by solving the system of  linear equations (for instance, by using [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule))
$$\begin{bmatrix}i&j&k\\i^2&j^2&k^2\\1&1&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\mu\\\gamma\\1\end{bmatrix}.$$
The corresponding $\mathbf q$ vector has all components zero,  except for $q_i=a$, $q_j=b$, and $q_k=c.$  Because $(\mu,\gamma)$          is in the interior of the triangle, each of $a,b,c$ will be positive. Also note that the matrix of the equation system will be invertible if $i,j,k$ are distinct.  If the same $(\mu,\gamma)$ value is in some other triangle, with vertices $v_r,v_s,v_t$, with $\{i,j,k\}\ne\{r,s,t\}$, then the same procedure will result in a different $\mathbf q$ vector.

Comment: Dear Kimchi, may I know if it is possible to write down an explicit formula for ${\bf q}$ (just one ${\bf q}$ is enough) in terms of ${\bf p}$, $\mu$ and $\gamma$ so that these two probability vectors have the same moments up to second order?